# No matter what I do I have Jagged Edges

Tags: adobe-photoshop

[image]

I have been trying to fix this for a while and now it is getting really annoying. All my text and anything that I fill is jagged. The image below I filled with the polygonal lasso tool and it looks very jagged.

I have the DPI on 300 and have tried going lower and higher but it doesn't effect anything. I have tried a lot of different ways to fix it over the year but nothing seems to work. It used to get worse every time I resized the image, but I ended up finding a fix for that.

I am not sure if this is just a me problem since I have a weird resolution 1400x900. But completely straight lines are jagged and it is very frustrating. Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: DPI does not affect your screen. You have turned antialiasing off.

Comment: Monitors use pixels to display. Only a monitor with a higher pixel density will help alleviate the display of pixel edges. You are also *zoomed in* on that image, so edges will be more apparent.

Comment: Also note that in that particular image there are **no** "completely straight lines". Every line is at an *angle*. Angles and curves may pixels more apparent.

Answer (score 2):

DPI is not the resolution of a digital image. It's the print output resolution. If you don't understand why, then have a look at this article: [The Myth of DPI](http://www.rideau-info.com/photos/mythdpi.html).

The main problem I see is that you have anti-aliasing disabled in the tool options for the Poylgon Select tool, which will make pixels jagged when you fill the selection.

Example showing zoomed in anti-aliased pixels (top) and anti-aliasing switched off (bottom)

[image]

Also you are zoomed in to 133%, which will make it look even worse. View images at 100% instead. You can't zoom in on raster images and not expect to see pixels.

Example showing zoom set to 100%. You can see anti-aliased pixels look smoother. Note that a line at an angle will always show jagged pixels to some degree in raster graphics. It will never look perfect, but that is only because they are made of pixels.

[image]